# Android: How to hide/show keyboard while focused on EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-virtual-keyboard

I have registration form and I need to show keyboard when user is focused in `EditText`. I had always problem with this and I used a lot of workarounds which are no longer working. Im surprised Android cant handle this basic thing like focusing between `EditText` on its own.

What is happening here: When I move from email EditText to password one, it will hide keyboard and password field is focused with indicator blinking without visible keyboard.

Code:

```
    emailEt.apply {
        onFocusChange {
            if (isFocused) app.showKeyboard(a) else app.hideKeyboard(this)
        }
        onEditorAction {
            passwordEt.requestFocus()
        }
        afterTextChanged {
            emailFieldValidation(true)
            validateData()
        }
    }

    passwordEt.apply {
        onFocusChange {
            if (isFocused) app.showKeyboard(a) else app.hideKeyboard(this)
        }
        onEditorAction {
            this.clearFocus()
        }
        afterTextChanged {
            passwordFieldValidation(true)
            validateData()
        }
    }

    resetData()
    emailEt.requestFocus()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-do-you-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-programmatically   and then use the **EditText** `isFocused()` method, to know when the **EditText** is focused.

Comment: Android does handle the keyboard on its own perfectly. But if you start messing with it, it's very easy to break it. Especially SHOW_FORCED takes all the bets off and you're managing the keyboard on your own (eg if your app gets killed, the keyboard stays on launcher). Try your layout in a fresh app, as long as EditTexts have `clickable` and `focusable` set to true, they will work on their own. Also, try on a different phone. If a hardware keyboard is hooked up (USB, BT, on emulator) then soft keyboard shouldn't open, that's a feature not a bug.

Comment: Well I unplugged phone from USB but its still not working. If I remove all of those focuschange listeners and let it handle it on its own, it will not even open keyboard while focused to first EditText on screen start.

Answer (score 1):

**Java**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

**Kotlin**

```
window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
```